# Why am I not getting my desired results from my while loops?

Tags: java, windows

I am new to this and could use some tips. My while loops don't seem to be working correctly. They aren't displaying my error messages or detecting any negative numbers I enter.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String employeeName;
double hourlyRate;
double hoursWorked;
double weeklyPay;

System.out.print("Enter the employee name: ");
employeeName = input.nextLine();

while (!("stop".equals(employeeName))){
    System.out.print("Enter the employee's hourly rate: ");
    hourlyRate = input.nextDouble();

    while (hourlyRate < 0) {
        System.out.println("Enter a positive number");
        hourlyRate = input.nextDouble();
    }

    System.out.print("Enter the number of hours the employee worked: ");         
    hoursWorked = input.nextDouble();

    while (hoursWorked < 0){
        System.out.println("Enter a positive number");
        hoursWorked = input.nextDouble();
    }

    System.out.println(employeeName + " Weekly pay: " + (hourlyRate * hoursWorked));
    employeeName = "stop";
}
```

When I run this and enter a negative number it doesn't display my error message. It just displays the results of the two numbers I entered as if they weren't negative ones, and it continues through the rest of the program. It's like it isn't detecting my negative number.

Comment: Fix the indentation? Please?

Comment: tried printing out `hourlyRate` to see that it is what you think it is?

Comment: Please keep the code grouped together, both for ease of reading and for ease of copy-paste.

Comment: @SecretClouds Are you serious? Your code already contains `System.out.print()` calls...

Comment: @John3136 Well yes I printed it.

Comment: Your code correctly prompts me when I try to give it a negative number.  My first thought is you haven't recompiled since you've made a change.  Your code as shown in your question works, so I'd double check you're running the bytecode you think you are running.

Comment: I think using class files from a different version of the source is the most likely cause. However, is there any locale in which one does not represent minus 3 as "-3"?

Comment: If that's the case then why does it work for other people but not for me?

Comment: @azurefrog I recompiled after making changes. Still not working. Anything else you can suggest?

Comment: The result of the experiment with my modified program confirms that the problem is that the OP is running a class file that does not correspond to the source code. I suggest starting a new question, with a different title and tags, on what can cause that, and how to cure it.

Comment: The new question should focus on the history of e.g. any renaming and package changes and the folder layout.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran your code and, unless I am misunderstanding your question, I do not see the behavior you are describing. It prompted me to enter a number again each time that I put in a negative value. I would try compiling and running again. Are you using an IDE?

Comment: Really? I ran it on NetBeans and on through my command line and it didn't work properly.

Comment: @SecretClouds Can you give us the exact failing inputs? It certainly works for the numbers I tried.

Comment: @SecretClouds It may be because of how System.out is being handled on the command line. Have you tried running directly in the NetBeans console?

Comment: Yes I tried that before I did through the console and it wasn't displaying my error messages, and it wasn't detecting my negative numbers. It just multiplies the values as if they were positive numbers that I entered.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan When I enter any number below zero it just continues on through the program. When I enter 'stop' as the name it does the same thing and enters 'stop' as the name for the end results.

Comment: @SecretClouds So it had the same, incorrect behavior on both the command line and on the console in NetBeans? That is very strange. I can tell you that your code does what you are intending it to do. My only guess is you have some sort of environment issue. I would try restarting NetBeans and Windows and see if this problem goes away.

Comment: @SecretClouds **Which** negative numbers did you type. The rest of us should be trying to duplicate an exact input that we know fails when you type it.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan I used -12 just recently and it didn't show my error message.

Comment: @mmaynar1 Yes, that is correct. Same error on both the command line and NetBeans. I will try restarting both and see how that works.

Comment: @SecretClouds Do you know how to use your debugger tool? I would set a breakpoint on one of those while loops and watch your hourlyRate or hoursWorked variable after typing in your input. At this point my only guesses are demon possession or you are trolling us all haha

Comment: @mmaynar1 No I do not know how to use the debugger tool. I am not trolling. I just want to get this to work on my computer.

Comment: @SecretClouds This is a complete shot in the dark, but try putting this line right after where you declare your input variable:  **input.useLocale( Locale.US );**

Comment: Where do I put it exactly? I tried where you said but it said "cannot find symbol". Remember, I'm kinda new to this.

Comment: @SecretClouds Put it on the second line right after                                                                                                        **Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);**

Comment: @SecretClouds Also, what do your import statements look like?

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code. It's just working fine. It's Throwing the error you intended to. 
what's the input you provided?

Comment: I typed a few different negative numbers and it just continued on to the next line. No error message popped up on my end. The same happens when I enter 'stop' as the name. No error message. It just continues on and 'stop' is in the output results as the name entered.

Comment: I ran your code with values like -20.0 and -20 it throws an error. please check whether you ran the same code you posted or not?.

Comment: Hmm. That's odd how it's not working on mine if the code seems to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

I ran the program and it runs fine. Maybe try restarting your IDE to flush out all the buffers..

Comment: Just restarted and ran it again. No luck.

Answer (score 0):

(This is really a comment, only posted as an answer so that I can include code.)

I took the program and added some debug output. I suggest trying out this version. If the problem is the suspected version issue, you either won't get the additional output or it will start working. If you get the extra output and the problem persists, please post the new output.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String employeeName;
    double hourlyRate;
    double hoursWorked;
    double weeklyPay;

    System.out.print("Enter the employee name: ");
    employeeName = input.nextLine();

    while (!("stop".equals(employeeName))) {

      System.out.print("Enter the employee's hourly rate: ");
      hourlyRate = input.nextDouble();
      System.out.println("First call: "+hourlyRate);

      while (hourlyRate < 0) {
        System.out.println("Enter a positive number");
        hourlyRate = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Second call: "+hourlyRate);
      }

      System.out.print("Enter the number of hours the employee worked: ");
      hoursWorked = input.nextDouble();
      System.out.println("Third call: "+hoursWorked);

      while (hoursWorked < 0) {
        System.out.println("Enter a positive number");
        hoursWorked = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Fourth call: "+hoursWorked);
      }

      System.out.println(employeeName + " Weekly pay: "
          + (hourlyRate * hoursWorked));
      employeeName = "stop";
    }
  }
}
```

Here is a sample copy-paste of the Eclipse console from running this program with positive input only:

```
Enter the employee name: xyzzy
Enter the employee's hourly rate: 10
First call: 10.0
Enter the number of hours the employee worked: 2
Third call: 2.0
xyzzy Weekly pay: 20.0
```

Comment: I just tried your version and it yielded the same results. I typed 'stop' in the employee name section and -12 for the hourly pay and hours worked. No error messages; it just continued to the next line no matter what I entered.

Comment: @SecretClouds Did you get any of the additional messages? The "First call" and ""Third call" messages are unconditional, so you would see them if you were really running my version of the program. Getting the same results from this program as from the old one would strongly support the theory that you are really running an old class file, not one corresponding to the current source.

Comment: What additional messages are you talking about? I get the messages that ask me to enter the employee name, hourly pay and hours worked, but when I enter something the results are the same as before. The negative numbers I enter are multiplied but the output isn't a negative value, it's positive. When I enter 'stop' is doesn't display "enter positive number" as it should. @PatriciaShanahan

Comment: Is there any way I can send you a snapshot of my results on here?

Comment: @SecretClouds Why not a text copy-paste in your question?

Comment: @SecretClouds See the sample output I edited into my answer, with positive inputs. Do you see lines like the ones beginning "First call" and "Third call"? If not, you are not running this program, but some old class file.

Comment: I guess I could. If I am running on an older class file as you say, can I do anything to fix it if that is the issue? I did copy your code into NetBeans and ran it but it was the same.

Comment: Okay I saw nothing like that. Just the same results from my previous code. How is it doing that if I copied yours and ran it?

Answer (score 0):

The Code Works Fine.
There is neither a compile errror nor any exception.
Also the Output is as Desired.